# Implementing user rating section for a website without user sign in

Tags: laravel, cookies, single-sign-on, openid-connect, openid

I want to implement a user review section in a website where I only need to show how much ratings the website has taken. I don't need user information or anything else. I just need to know how much rating a particular post has gotten.

I want to achieve this without users signs in. I researched a little bit about open ID which kinds of helps in this matter. Has anyone implemented this kind of scenario with open ID in laravel ??

Or if there is any better way to achieve this purpose I am open to your valuable suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to follow **[this article](https://darutk.medium.com/oauth-2-0-and-openid-connect-implementation-in-laravel-authlete-4d32802ab335)** to implement openID in laravel and I think it will be helpful for you because implement it and explain in detail step by step